# Python: Primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes and dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, primes

Hey I was trying to write some code to get primes using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
Employing a dictionary with numbers for the range to check I set the value to True when I checked it is not a prime. But something is not working correctly and instead of skipping to the next number if the value is True (= already checked) it tests it again.
What am I doing wrong?

---

```
max=12
checked={}
primes =[]
numbers=[]

for i in xrange(2,max):
    numbers.append(i)
    checked[i] = False      

for i in numbers:
    if checked[i] == True:
        continue 
        #if the number was already checked continue with next
    else:
        primes.append(i) 
        #lowest unchecked number is always a prime
        checked[i] = True 
        for x in numbers:
            if x%i==0:
            #checking off all the multiples of the prime
                checked[x]=True
                print x

print primes
```

Now I get this Output

```
2
4
6
8
10
3
6
9
5
10
7
11
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

Clearly the 6 and 10 are checked twice instead of skipped.

Comment: We are not your personal debugging squad. [Debug your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and once you isolated the issue and still don't understand what was wrong, that's when you can ask a focused question that is easy for us to answer

Comment: You are missing the keyword `for` in the first loop

Comment: it works for me when I replace what Ian said. Otherwise it doesn't compile at all.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment Bart. The code is working fine, but not as intended and therefore looping longer then needed.
Being a beginner and having used Stackoverflow a couple of times to find some reference in questions others asked, I thought it was Ok to get some help here. Apparently not...

Comment: Yeah the for was somehow deleted during formatting posting the question.

Comment: It is I think part of the culture in Stack Overflow that questions without a clear action point for the answerer are frowned upon, but that off course does not mean that people being jerks to the guy with 1 rep point is OK. You see not all of us are like that. I still do not understand why you think this is looping more times than needed. How many times should it loop for max=30? I get 28.

Comment: Congratulations, you've learned your first important programming lesson:  There are some people that are major jerks to beginners.  That being said, you will get best results here if you are specific with your error messages along with the output you expected vs what you got.  I found [The Online Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) extremely helpful when first learning to code (and still today).  Don't hesitate to ask questions here (but do a little of your own research first!)

Comment: Use pastebin.com or edit your question. Can't add a lot of nicely formatted code in the comments. :)

Comment: It checks 6 and 10 twice because 6 is a multiple of the primes 2 and 3 and 10 is a multiple of the primes 5 and 2. If you dont want it to do that add: 
if x%i==0 and checked[x] is not True:
although it wont save you anything performance-wise..

Comment: Ahh now I get where I thought wrong. The first if just checks the prime itself, later I would have to make sure the multiples don't get checked more then once... thanks a lot.

Comment: No prob. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please accept my answer since it helped you :)

Comment: @Benster The link in my comment is to a post that explains, to beginners, the act of debugging a small program such as yours. As such, I would assume that it is helpful. It is okay to ask for help. If you don't know how to find your error then you could, for example, ask for direction on how to find your error. Learning how to find your error is _much_ more helpful to you in the long run than us simply telling you what's wrong. Re `the code is working fine but not as intended`: Then it's not working fine.

Comment: just a quick note, there's no reason to use a dictionary to indicate straight `True/False`. you can use a `set` instead, and then do something like `if v in set:` and then `set.add(v)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.
Just replace the sixth line with:

```
for i in xrange(2,max+1):
```

The +1 is because without it the algorithm does not check the max number the user gave.

Also:

```
numbers = range(2,max+1)
```

It doesnt really matter if you use the generator xrange, but then save all the numbers in a list anyway, so why not do it in one line.

To address the OP's clarification in the comments:

It checks 6 and 10 twice because 6 is a multiple of the primes 2 and 3 and 10 is a multiple of the primes 5 and 2. If you dont want it to do that add:

```
if x%i==0 and checked[x] is not True:
```

although it wont save you anything performance-wise..

Comment: clarified:  xrange(2,5) will include the numbers 2, 3, and 4, hence the plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

```
max=12
checked={}
primes =[]
numbers=[]

for i in xrange(2,max):
    numbers.append(i)
    checked[i] = False      

for i in numbers:
    if checked[i] == True:
        continue 
        #if the number was already checked continue with next
    else:
        primes.append(i) 
        #lowest unchecked number is always a prime
        checked[i] = True 
        for x in numbers:
            if x%i==0 and checked[x]==False:
            #checking off all the multiples of the prime
                checked[x]=True
                print x

print primes
```